# Динамичный массив

Tags: массивы, c

Надо рандомно выбрать массив данных с частотой, чтоб сыграть мелодию

```
char midi_1[][] = {
  {2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2637, 2637, 2793, 2793, 2489, 2489},
  {2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2637, 2637},
  {2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2637, 2637}
};
```

Вся загвоздка в том, что длина массива с мелодией может быть любая, компилятор это не принимает (an array can't have elements of this type).

Как ещё можно реализовать эту задачу?

**Обновление**

Если очень просто, мне нужно получить рандомный массив, но массивы могут быть разной длины. Что-то вроде `midi_1[rang(0, 2)]`.

В js это могло бы выглядеть как-то так: http://code.re/6L5

Comment: При чем тут char? И зачем массив массивов? А длительность у нот какая? Не понятно, какую задачу вы реализуете и каким образом.

Comment: Я про ноты так сказал, чтоб не было сообщений типо "покажите весь код, может можно вообще от этого отказаться". Задержка уже есть

Задача под микроконтроллер

Есть "альбомы", в каждом "альбоме" есть мелодии. У нас есть только название такого "альбома", надо выбрать из него рандомную мелодию

Comment: @Fangog, ничего толком не понял.

Вам нужно на стадии компиляции написать структуру (что-то вроде матрицы) чисел с разным размером строк?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

[[@Fangog](/users/8519/fangog)](/users/8519/fangog), что-то в таком духе пойдет?

```
#include <stdio.h>    // здесь I/O
#include <stdlib.h>   // здесь rand()
// а этот "инклюд" нужен только для теста с генератором случайных чисел
// будем инициализировать его текущим количеством секунд с 1/1/1970
#include <time.h>

/* 
   Вот это массивы чисел, которые вы определяете перед компиляцией,
   "забиваете" в текст программы.
   Насколько помню, у вас что-то о треках,
   тогда каждый массив это трек, который предстоит случайно выбрать.
   Имена массивов совершенно произвольны (в рамках синтаксиса и др. правил языка C
*/
int a0[] = {2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2637, 2637, 2793, 2793, 2489, 2489};
int a1[] = {12217, 12349, 12349, 12489, 12637, 12637};
int a2[] = {32217, 32349, 32349, 32489, 32217, 32349, 32349, 32489, 32217, 32349, 32349, 32489, 32637, 32637};

// макрос дает размер массива в ЭЛЕМЕНТАХ (не байтах)
#define SZA(x) sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])

// этот макрос сократит количество буковок, которые пришлось бы набивать
// им мы инициализируем элемент массива midi_1[], в котором храним указатель на трек и длину трека
#define DCL(x) {x, SZA(x)}

// структура элемента массива, котрый описывает треки
// существенное отличие от записи в JS
// midi_1 [] = { {1,2,3}, {1,2}, ... {1,2,3,4,5}};
// в том, что в отличие от JS C не связывает с массивом его размер(!)
// об этом мы сами должны думать (что и делаем, описывая эту структуру)
struct a {
  int *a,  // указатель на первое число трека
      sz;  // количество чисел в треке
} midi_1 [] = {DCL(a0), DCL(a1), DCL(a2)};
// midi_1 [] - массив этих структур, размер определяется при заполнении

int 
main(int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  srand(time(0));
  struct a *p = midi_1 + (rand() % SZA(midi_1));
  // p -- указывает на случайный описатель трека
  int i;

  // печатаем последовательно все числа трека
  for (i = 0; i < p->sz; i++)
    printf ("%d ", p->a[i]);
  puts("");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Если есть вопросы, попозже вечером попробую ответить.

**Update**

Добавил комментариев, надеюсь стало понятней, почему делаю именно так.

Comment: Выглядит сложновато для такой задачи. Раз так, не менее ресурсоемко будет создать ещё один массив с адресами других массивов?

Comment: Тут один массив с адресами и размерами 3-х массивов с вашими числами.

Вы имеете в виду сделать 2 "параллельных" массива, вместо одного массива структур, т.е. один массив с адресами, а другой с размерами?

Если у Вас 64-бит система, то сэкономите 12 байт, а на 32-бит будет одинаково. Только писать больше и вероятность несогласованности при изменениях выше.

--

Вы пишете -- "сложновато". А в чем именно затруднения?

Comment: У меня 8-битная система) 

Я пока только учусь си, но это могло бы выглядеть как-то так http://code.re/6LN

Или нет?

Comment: Нет (учите тщательней).

--

Вы сделали массив `arr[]` для 3-х чисел и инициализировали его первыми числами из массивов `a0[]`, `a1[]` и `a2[]`.

Это совершенно не соответствует той программе на JS, которую Вы приводили в качестве примера.

--

Во что в 8-ми битной системе (а какой проц?) будет транслироваться мой код -- не знаю. Подозреваю, что размер адреса (указателя) и int одинаков, но не знаю. 

Если у Вас `gcc`, то `gcc -S prog.c` сгенерит ассемблерный код в файле prog.s

Comment: Кстати, раз Вы только учитесь, то, пожалуй, несколько комментариев к моему коду не повредит.

Сейчас отредактирую текст ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, выполняться все это будет на atmega324pa

Щас попробую скомпилировать

---

Проверил, компилятор на такое решение не ругается (на сколько я знаю, си для микроконтроллеров вроде немного отличается).

И понял, что надо бы хорошо подучить и понять указатели

Благодарю за решение

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
int *midi_1[] = {
    (int[]){2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2637, 2637, 2793, 2793, 2489, 2489},
    (int[]){2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2637, 2637},
    (int[]){2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2217, 2349, 2349, 2489, 2217, 2349,
             2349, 2489, 2637, 2637}
};
```

(украдено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711029/276994), [проверка](http://ideone.com/FtUxER)).

Подумайте о том, как код узнает о размерах каждой из строк вашего массива.

Comment: @VladD, и как этим можно воспользоваться?

Я попробовал. g++ не компилирует, gcc пишет warnings, но главное, я так и не смог сообразить, а как обращаться к числам?

Более того, когда стал смотреть отладчиком, то почему-то после *(midi_1 + 9) (т.е. последнего 2489 в первой строке) я вижу только нули

(целая страница (4K) нулей, а потом чтение уже недоступно...).

Comment: @avp: Хм, и правда. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @avp: Вот так у меня работает: http://pastebin.com/4wqBUTSd http://ideone.com/1M996S

Comment: @VladD, так понятно. Массив указателей. 

Только как  размер этих подмассивов вытащить (описать во время компиляции)?

Comment: @avp: Никак. :( Ну то есть, без вашего трюка, обернуть в макрос по вкусу.

С другой стороны, у ТС ведь данные не с потолка берутся? Из этой самой предметной области, возможно, возьмутся и длины массивов.